# How to place AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language) files in the correct folder when building Unity project for the Android platform?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, aidl

I have a unity project which is supposed to be built for the Android platform. This project is should communicate with another android app through some interfaces that are defined in an AIDL file. In the final APK file structure, this AIDL file should be added to an “aidl” folder and this “aidl” folder should be created in /src/main folder of the project alongside “java” and “res” folders.

I can achieve this by exporting the unity project to an android project, open the project in android studio, then add the aidl folder to the structure, paste the AIDL files inside this folder, and build the APK using the android studio.

However, I was wondering if this could be achieved directly from unity, without having to export the project for android studio. I have already tried adding the AIDL files in my unity project, but apparently, unity doesn`t recognize AIDL files as an android supported file (unlike java and Kotlin files which are recognized by unity as android supported files).

Any help is much appreciated.